# PHP posting to twitter in bitly url format

Tags: php, json, twitter

I've managed to put together the following script:

```
<?php

/* make a URL small */
function make_bitly_url($url,$login,$appkey,$format = 'xml',$version = '2.0.1')
{
    //create the URL
    $bitly = 'http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version='.$version.'&longUrl='.urlencode($url).'&login='.$login.'&apiKey='.$appkey.'&format='.$format;

    //get the url
    //could also use cURL here
    $response = file_get_contents($bitly);

    //parse depending on desired format
    if(strtolower($format) == 'json')
    {
        $json = @json_decode($response,true);
        return $json['results'][$url]['shortUrl'];
    }
    else //xml
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        return 'http://bit.ly/'.$xml->results->nodeKeyVal->hash;
    }
}


//function to get the url of the event! 
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

/* usage */
$short = make_bitly_url('http://site.com/viewEvent.php?id=2323232','bitlyuser','bitlyapikey','json');
echo 'The short URL is:  '.$short . "<br>"; 
echo "PATH: ". curPageURL();
// returns:  http://bit.ly/11Owun
?>
```

Now this code can produce the a short url of whatever is passed to it. I have a tweet button on my site that I got from [twitter developer site](https://dev.twitter.com/). it works in that it posts the fully link of the page it is currently on...so not the shorten version. Now i want when that twitter button is pressed for it produce a short url so that I could share on my site's account. How is that done?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just set the `data-url` option to the bitly url. e.g.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php echo make_bitly_url('http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],LOGIN,APPKEY); ?>">Tweet</a>
```